# iPad app to manage photos stored in cloud?

Tags: ipad, photos, network

I currently have several thousand (15GB) photographs stored on a PC. I would like to move them all to the cloud somewhere and use the iPad to manage them - change names, put in folders, etc. I also want to be able to copy pictures from the iPad to my collection in the cloud. I'm not committed to where in cloudland I should store my pictures - maybe PicasaWeb, dropbox, Amazon S3, or something else. I'm happy to choose based on what would work the best with an iPad management app.

Answer (score 1):

### [Adobe Revel](http://www.adobe.com/products/revel.html) ($5.99pm or $59.99py)

Adobe Revel (previously called carousel) is a cloud photo editing and storage app, similar to [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) with the added function of being able to store images in the cloud. It is a subscription based service.

However this is currently only available on iOS, and Mac, with both Windows and Android currently in development.

If you were desperate to use this solution, you can get the iPad app, and sync the photos over iTunes and then use the app to pop the images in the cloud, however this would be time consuming, the Adobe website has a notify me, button on Windows/Android, so this platform will be available.

Comment: Sounds intriguing when there is a Win version, otherwise I'll have to transfer the 15gb library to a bow wowed Mac and then transfer them to Adobe. But, if no better solution pops up, maybe I'll do that. It's nice that Revel has a thirty-day free trial so I can check how this works.

Comment: I've looked into Revel more and it's not really a "cloud storage" app, in the sense that it would replace my local computer as the primary storage place. Revel **assumes** that your primary store of images is on your local Macintosh (and eventually Windows). It does apparently make copies into the cloud, but this is NOT considered to be primary. **As evidence of this, they don't provide a way to back it up!**  So I guess I'm still looking for a solution where the cloud is the "center" of the storage strategy.

Comment: You could use Dropbox as the source folder on your desktop. That way you would be syncing to a cloud based service which is also on your desktop? Its not totally cloud based but it does offer that back-up option.